# Determine if a file has changed

Tags: bash, server, find, cron

I have created a bash script that run everyday 06:00 AM to check if a file has been changed between 05:00 AM - 06:00 AM.

Our server automatic upload this file upload.xml everyday on 05:00 AM and replaces the old one, therefore I created a bash script that will check if this file hase been uploaded.

My bash script not working as I want. Everyday sends email from bash script that tell me at this file has not been uploaded or changed, and checked the file has been already uploaded with the new changed time.

So what is wrong with my code.

here is my bash script code.

```
[[ -z `find /home/USER/public_html/upload.xml -mmin -60` ]]

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    mail -s "File has not been changed" admin@mydomain.com
else
    echo -e "file has been changed"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$()` instead of legacy `backticks`.

```
var="$(find /home/USER/public_html/ -type f -mmin -60 -name "upload.xml")"
if [ -z "$var" ] #checking if a SET variable is empty
then
    mail -s "File has not been changed" admin@mydomain.com
else
    echo -e "file has been changed"
fi
```

---

**Notes**

- In find you specify the path first then filter for a file using `-name`
- Double quoting the variables does no harm here.

Comment: Thanks for you pretty answer. Naw I have replaced with your codes. So this script check if the file has been changed between 60 min ago?

Comment: @Alex Imho -60 should be interpreted within last 60 minutes and +60 as not within last 60 minutes